# Auto send message and mails?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sms

Ok I know there are many possible duplicate questions but none answers my question.

According to Apple's ￼[￼App Store Review Guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf) (if it is the official one) I can only find 4 rules stating anything about messaging

5.5 Apps that use Push Notifications to send unsolicited messages, or for the purpose of phishing or spamming will be rejected

6.5 Apps that use Game Center service to send unsolicited messages, or for the purpose of phishing or spamming will be rejected

21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS

22.6 Apps that enable anonymous or prank phone calls or SMS/MMS messaging will be rejected

According to me these rules does not restrict auto sending a message completely, if we have user's concern of sending the SMS.

Now I want to know is there's anyway that I can auto send SMS on a scheduled time when the app is suspended, like we can fire UILocalNotification?
If Yes then how and if No then why?

I also don't want to use any third party API or some server side programming. I want to send a simple SMS from phone.

Comment: One more thing..
I don't want to use any third party API or server side programming, I want to send the SMS from the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can not send an e-mail or SMS via the Apple provided SDK without the user sending the messages.

You could setup your own mail server of SMS server to provide a solution to this, but you will not be able to do it with the Apple provided SDK.

The reason why this is implement this way is to protect the user, since you could just send 100 SMS to some kind of server number and thus make the user unaware of the costs.
Or you app could start spamming user with email by sending email without the users consent.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for straight and simple answer.